# Boolean Difference deforming flat plane

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to cut a circle into a cube (as pictured) and the boolean modifier with the sphere is deforming the face of the cube. This is the second boolean modifier (the first being for the speaker cone below). Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: You can take screenshots on windows by pressing "printscr"  You can take screenshots on mac by pressing command shift 4, and then dragging over what you want to take a picture of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give a small suggestion when you add the cube add a little thickness (solidify modifier). Then use the boolean modifier it work perfect you can see below.

[image: boolean gif]